# SQL Oracle summary table query with top-n on each group

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two table with desc like this

Transaction Table
**CustID** | fk to customer table,
**Amount** | amount spend on each transaction

Customer Table
**CustID** | pk,
**Age** | customer age

i need to make
a query to group or bucketing the customer by age range
and i need to make top-3 amount highest amount each age group also the bottom 3 amount or lowest spender
so far what i have done is
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ccf988ec525dc133cf7825ba052e8054

[what i manage so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZ6wP.png)
[inner query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eeca.png)

I have try to use CTE, but still not sure how to get the top 3 on each group/bottom 3 of each group
[with cte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWW4A.png)

the problem is on the first picture on the first row, the return is more than 3/ they append all of the records while i just need only the top 3

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to find the highest and the lowest and then you can use conditional aggregation within `LISTAGG` to only display the highest and lowest in their corresponding lists:

```sql
select age_bucket, 
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN max_rn <= 3 THEN amount END, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY amount DESC) AS TOP_3_AMOUNT,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN min_rn <= 3 THEN amount END, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY amount ASC ) AS BOTTOM_3_AMOUNT
FROM   (
  SELECT amount,
         age_bucket,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY age_bucket ORDER BY amount DESC) AS max_rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY age_bucket ORDER BY amount ASC ) AS min_rn
  FROM   (
    select t.amount,
           case
           when c.age <= 20             THEN '<= 20'
           when c.age between 21 and 30 THEN '21-30'
           when c.age between 31 and 40 THEN '31-40'
           when c.age between 41 and 50 THEN '41-50'
           when c.age >= 51             THEN '>= 51'
           END as age_bucket 
    from   transaction t
           join customer c on t.cust_id=c.cust_id
  )
)
WHERE max_rn <= 3
OR    min_rn <= 3
group by age_bucket
order by age_bucket asc;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0f388ecf07a128a67ca9e3b2d701b30)*

---

> I need to make it only top 3 or bottom 3 distinct by the customer id

```sql
select age_bucket, 
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN max_rn <= 3 THEN amount END, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY amount DESC) AS TOP_3_AMOUNT,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN min_rn <= 3 THEN amount END, ',')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY amount ASC ) AS BOTTOM_3_AMOUNT
FROM   (
  SELECT amount,
         age_bucket,
         CASE max_cust_rn
         WHEN 1
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY age_bucket ORDER BY amount DESC)
         END AS max_rn,
         CASE min_cust_rn
         WHEN 1
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY age_bucket ORDER BY amount ASC )
         END AS min_rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT amount,
           age_bucket,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY age_bucket, cust_id ORDER BY amount DESC) AS max_cust_rn,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY age_bucket, cust_id ORDER BY amount ASC ) AS min_cust_rn
    FROM   (
      select t.amount,
             t.cust_id,
             case
             when c.age <= 20             THEN '<= 20'
             when c.age between 21 and 30 THEN '21-30'
             when c.age between 31 and 40 THEN '31-40'
             when c.age between 41 and 50 THEN '41-50'
             when c.age >= 51             THEN '>= 51'
             END as age_bucket 
      from   transaction t
             join customer c on t.cust_id=c.cust_id
    )
  )
  WHERE max_cust_rn = 1
  OR    min_cust_rn = 1
)
WHERE max_rn <= 3
OR    min_rn <= 3
group by age_bucket
order by age_bucket asc;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7932b78fda38627c775eca777c737943)*

Comment: this solution working 
but i think i need to adjust this query a bit, because i need to make it only top 3 or bottom 3 distinct by the customer id 
could you help me with that ?

Comment: so the top 3 is 70000 from cust id 5, 9000 from cust id 1
and last is from 2500 cust id 4 
https://imgur.com/zaxB4WE

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no descriptions of tables, I just tried to change a little bit
Could you try:

```
SELECT   age_bucket,
         Listagg(
         CASE
                  WHEN seqnumbyeachcusttop = 1 THEN amount
         END, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY amount DESC)            AS test_top_3_amouny,
         listagg(amount, ',') within GROUP (ORDER BY amount DESC) AS top_3_principal
FROM     (
                  SELECT   age_bucket,
                           seqnumbyeachcusttop,
                           amount,
                           row_number() OVER (partition BY amount ORDER BY amount DESC) rn
                  FROM     (
                                    SELECT   t.amount                                                          AS amount,
                                             t.cust_id                                                         AS cust_id,
                                             row_number() OVER (partition BY t.cust_id ORDER BY t.amount DESC) AS seqnumbyeachcusttop,
                                             CASE
                                                      WHEN c.age <= 20 THEN ' <= 20'
                                                      WHEN c.age BETWEEN 21 AND      30 THEN '21-30'
                                                      WHEN c.age BETWEEN 31 AND      40 THEN '31-40'
                                                      WHEN c.age BETWEEN 41 AND      50 THEN '41-50'
                                                      WHEN c.age >= 51 THEN '>= 51'
                                             END AS age_bucket
                                    FROM     TRANSACTION t
                                    JOIN     customer c
                                    ON       t.cust_id=c.cust_id ))
WHERE    rn <= 3) GROUP BY age_bucket ORDER BY age_bucket ASC;
```

Comment: thank you for the help i have found more suitable answer